# How do I change decimal dot into decimal comma?

Tags: excel, vba, decimal, separator

I have a column containing numbers with mixed decimal separators.
[image: example]

I need to use "," as separator.

How do I change dot into comma?

```vb
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("RAW").Range("A1")
    .Value = Replace(.Value, ".", ",")
End With
```

The point is stored as text
[image: look at it]

Is there any way to store it as general/numeric?

I tried this

```vb
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("RAW").Range("A1")
    .NumberFormat = "General"
    .Value = Replace(.Value, ".", ",")
    .NumberFormat = "General"
    .Value = .Value
End With
```

Comment: I got error: Type Mismatch :(

Comment: yeah, sorry. just typo

Comment: @JvdV could you please look at my answer below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A single cell could be solved quick and dirty through:

```
.Value = Replace(.Value, ".", ",")*1
```

Or:

```
.Value = CSng(Replace(.Value, ".", ","))
```

If you happen to have a range to process, you could use:

```
Sub Test()

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("RAW").Range("A1:A3")
    .Replace ".", ","
    .TextToColumns
End With

End Sub
```

Per column:

```
Sub Test()

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("RAW").Range("C2:D4")
    .Replace ".", ","
    For Each col In .Columns
        col.TextToColumns
    Next
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: ok but I get error: "Microsoft Office Excel can convert only one column at a time. The range can be many rows tall but no more than one column wide. Try again by selecting cells in one column only"

how to iterate through multiple columns?